# alarmmanager (show class after every reboot)

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I've an intent that starts a new class at fixed time (and date). This intents start at fixed date BUT also at every reboot (also after the date and time are are in the past). In my code the New.class starts at 26/12/12 - 21.30 but if I reboot emulator after that time, New.class starts automatically. Why? Thanks!

PS: this code is within an Autostart class (public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {)

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getDefault(), Locale.getDefault());
cal.set(Calendar.DATE,26);
cal.set(Calendar.MONTH,Calendar.DECEMBER);  
cal.set(Calendar.YEAR,2012);
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 21);  
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);       
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);       

Intent intent3 = new Intent(context, New.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,intent3, 0);
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's by design. See the [documentation of the `set()` method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#set%28int,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29):

"If the time occurs in the past, the alarm will be triggered immediately."

If you do *not* want this to happen, you shouldn't schedule the Alarm. That is, you should check yourself whether to call `set()` within the BroadcastReceiver.